# How do I return an empty collection or default value in C#

Tags: c#

so I have a generic function that calls a web service and converts it to whatever type you call the function with.  However if you call CallUrl<SomeValue[]> - I don't want to return null, I want to return an empty list.  I'm currently returning DefaultOrEmpty() - where that looks like:

```cs
private static T DefaultOrEmpty<T>()
{
   return typeof(T).IsArray 
      ? (T)(object)Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T).GetElementType()!, 0) 
      : default;
}
```

which works, but seems ridiculously complicated - is there a cleaner way to write this function?

Comment: How about  `Enumerable.Empty<TResult>`?

Comment: @MickyD OP's problem is that for that method T is an item, not the array (as in OP's code), though I do agree that would be the sanest approach.

Comment: Do you want `DefaultOrEmpty<string>()` to return null or an empty string? Or more generally, given a reference type `Foo`, should `DefaultOrEmpty<Foo>()` return null or an initialized instance of `Foo`?

Comment: Maybe look to see how `Dictionary<.>` does it?

Comment: So DefaultOrEmpty is a helper function to CallUrl?

Comment: yes - default or empty is a helper function to call url.   So DefaultOrEmpty<string> should be null... DefaultOrEmpty<int> should be 0.   DefaultOrEmpty<int[]> should be an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "collection", you mean an array, specifically, I don't see anything particularly wrong with your array initialization as it's perfectly understandable, but here's a slightly shorter method if that's what you're aiming for:

```
private static T DefaultOrEmpty<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).IsArray
       ? (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 0)
       : default;
}
```

Or to support multidimensional arrays (which were not supported in the original method):

```
private static T DefaultOrEmpty<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        var args = Enumerable.Repeat(0, typeof(T).GetArrayRank())
            .Cast<object>()
            .ToArray();
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    }
    
    return default;
}
```

Comment: if T is int [] - Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(T),0) returns T[][]

Comment: @DarrenOakey That's not true. See it in action [here](https://rextester.com/HWFXBG86583).

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough to just inline.

```
T[] DefaultOrEmpty<T>()
=> Array.Empty<T>();
```

If you sometimes return an array & sometimes a unary value, you could avoid the reflection by using function overloads and extension methods.
Here's an example:

```
public static class Extensions
{

//drop in replacement
public static T? DefaultOrEmpty<T>(this T? value)
    => value?? default;

public static T DefaultOrEmpty<T>(this T? value, T defaultValue)
    => value ?? defaultValue;

public static T DefaultOrEmpty<T>(this T? value, Func<T> defaultValueFactory)
    => value ?? defaultValueFactory();

//drop in replacement
public static T[] DefaultOrEmpty<T>(this T[]? value)
    => value ?? Array.Empty<T>();

public static T[] DefaultOrEmpty<T>(this T[]? value, Func<T[]> defaultValueFactory)
    => value ?? defaultValueFactory();
```

}

Which can be called like so:

```
int? num1 = null;
Console.WriteLine(num1.DefaultOrEmpty());
Console.WriteLine(num1.DefaultOrEmpty(99));
string[] names = null;
Console.WriteLine(names.DefaultOrEmpty().Length);
```

Comment: That won't work because `T` in `DefaultOrEmpty<T>` is the array type (or another standalone type), not the _element_ type. The OP wants to do `DefaultOrEmpty<int[]>`, not `DefaultOrEmpty<int>`. The latter should return `0`, not an empty array of `int` (which is what the former should do). Otherwise, the whole method would be redundant and the OP can use `Array.Empty<T>()` directly.

Comment: I added some more info for context. I don't see the need to specify an array type parameter.

Comment: this is hidden inside a CallUrl function - that can take any type - so you can say:
callUrl<SomeObject>( "http...", someInput) and it will work with an json web service - but many services return a json array - so you say callUrl<SomeObject[]>( "http://blah") - and it just seems better in this case to return an empty array on a 404, rather than a null

Comment: Function overloads might be able to handle this without reflection. I've updated the answer.